# Create a mysql view from sql server tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a mysql view from some sql server tables but I have not found the way. I have created a lot of views and tables in sql server from mysql tables with a linked server on sql server management studio but now I'm trying to do it to the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that, MySQL does not have the concept of linked servers connecting to other RDBMS products. The [federated table engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-usagenotes.html) can only connect to other MySQL servers.

You have to push the data from the ms sql server side into MySQL tables and you can create a view based on those tables within MySQL.